# Plural possession of singular items

Tags: gramática, posesivos

In English, when multiple people each possess a single item individually, we still state that item in its plural form, like “the people and their families” not “their family” (which would imply shared possession for all the people) even if each “person” only has one “family.” How is this expressed/differentiated in Spanish? For example, does "Las personas y su familia" imply that each person has a family? Or that they all share a singular family? Or is it ambiguous and based on context? Another more clear example would be "Mis amigos y sus madres" vs "Mis amigos y su madre".

What about "El auto de las personas ricas suele ser de alta gama" or something like that? Does that make sense or should it be either "El auto de una persona rica suele ser de alta gama" or "Los autos de las personas ricas suelen ser de alta gama".

Sorry if this isn’t super clear; I know this example sucks but I’ve struggled trying to come up with how to phrase this question and even more searching for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En castellano siempre tiene que **concordar** el accidente de la partícula gramatical—los artículos, determinantes, pronombres, etc.—con el de la palabra lexical—sustantivo, adjetivo, verbo, etc. La concordancia puede/debe ser en número, género y tiempo (en el caso de los verbos).

De acuerdo a esto, los adjetivos y pronombres posesivos deben ser empleados según la persona a la que desee hacer referencia (1ª, 2ª y 3ª ; singular y plural), y luego deben ser conjugados en base al género y número del objeto. Para ver las diferencias en cuanto al número, que por lo que entiendo es tu duda, compará estos pares:

- 'Mi libro' y 'mi**s** libro**s**' [yo]
- 'Tu auto' y 'tu**s** auto**s**'  [tú, vos]
- 'Su casa' y 'su**s** casa**s**' [él, ella, usted, ustedes, ellos]
- 'Nuestra ciudad' y 'nuestra**s** ciudad**es**' [nosotros]
- 'Vuestro servicio' y 'vuestro**s** servicio**s**' [vosotros]

En cada caso, la primera construcción hace referencia a un único objeto, mientras que el segundo hace referencia a múltiples objeto. Pero el número del posesivo—o del sustantivo, ya que ambos deben concordar—no te permite saber la persona a la que refiere. Para ello necesitás prestar atención al tipo de posesivo en sí que aparece en la construcción. Notá que en el caso de 'su/sus' no podés saber a qué persona hace referencia a menos que obtengás el contexto en el que aparece el posesivo.

Por lo tanto, en:

> Las personas y su familia

estás denotando que el grupo de personas al que te referís tiene una familia en común, en cambio en:

> Las personas y su**s** familia**s**

hay al menos dos personas que no comparten familia. Lo mismo pasa en 'Mis amigos y su(s) madre(s)'.

En el segundo caso, las siguientes frases de seguro son correctas:

> **Los** auto**s** de la**s** persona**s** rica**s** suele**n** ser de alta gama.

> **El** auto de **una**  persona rica suele ser de alta gama.

Pero:

> #El auto de la**s** persona**s** rica**s** suele ser de alta gama.

si bien no es un error gramatical (fijate que todos los sintagmas concuerdan), la frase no deja de ser ambigua. Es común escuchar frases así en el lenguaje coloquial y en este ejemplo el significado del mensaje se reconstruye fácilmente por el contexto en el que es escuchada la oración. Pero abusar de esto puede llevarnos a la confusión:

> Las plazas de mi ciudad son grandes.

> #La plaza de mi ciudad es grande.

En el segundo caso estoy denotando que mi ciudad tiene una única plaza, por lo tanto se perdió el significado de la primera oración.

Comment: Hola tac te agradezco la respuesta. Edité mi pregunta con unas aclaraciones.  Entiendo que frases como l**as** person**as** etc. tienen que concordar en número, género, etc. pero mi pregunta es lo que se interpreta con una frase como "las personas y su familia" o "los humanos tienen un cerebro". Es que cada quien tiene **una** familia o **un** cerebro? O que todas las personas tienen una familia colectivamente y todos los humanos comparten un cerebro? No sé si me explico, y me imagino que es una pregunta tonta pero bueno

Comment: OP wants to know about the distributive use of possessives.

Comment: All humans have a brain versus All humans have brains would be the same difference in Spanish.

Comment: @ColbyWright Ya la edité, creo que ahora sí responde específicamente a lo que preguntaste.